# Is there a model describing the relation between language and culture?

Tags: theoretical-linguistics, sociolinguistics

Is there a model describing the relation between language and culture ? I'm looking for a model integrating culture as part of the process of human communication.

Comment: So is everybody else, really. Probably [Dan Everett's work](http://www.amazon.com/Language-The-Cultural-Tool-Vintage/dp/0307473805) is a good start. Depending on what kind of "model" you're looking for; it's not written in Python.

Comment: Could you be more specific what you mean by _culture_ or give examples of the kind of things the model you're looking for should be able to explain? Otherwise answers will be very broad and might still not answer your actual question. Still, you might want to look at [conceptual metaphors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conceptual_metaphors), which I personally find a very good model/tool for integrating some aspects of culture into the study of language.

Comment: a theoretical model?   a computer model?   a study of a small and isolated culture?